# Adding class to an element javascript problemm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

if i add a class to an element after the page has been loaded, using javascript, would the properties related to the same element get updated instantly?

Comment: pls show us some codes

Comment: What are "properties related to the same element"?  Did you try to do what you're intending?  Was it unsuccessful?  Show us your attempt and explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, whenever you add new class to an element and that class have some styles in your referenced css files, then it'll be applied.

```
<p class="test">This is a test</p> 

.red {
    color: red;
}

$('.test').addClass('red');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7LdbH/)**

Answer (score 0):

with `jquery` something like so:

```
$(function(){
$('yourElemet').addclass('yourclass');
})
```

in JavaScript:

```
<body onload="script();">
or

document.onload = function ...
or even

window.onload = function ..
```